# Checking if two routes (expressed in latitude and longitude) are opposing each other

Tags: php, math, latitude-longitude

I've been busting my head with this one.
I have two routes:

**Route 1**

> Starting point:
>
> - lat: 44.426767
> - lng: 26.102538
>
> Ending point:
>
> - lat: 45.031428
> - lng: 23.268939

**Route 2**

> Starting point:
>
> - lat: 45.095770
> - lng: 24.362799
>
> Ending point:
>
> - lat: 44.857492
> - lng: 24.881478

Now, I know that the two routes are opposing each other(if I draw them on the map), but I can't quite figure out how to tell this mathematically. 
I've tried looking into math vectors, but I don't get how to express a vector by latitude and longitude coordinates.

I would really appreciate if you can give me a push in the right direction, thanks!

PS: I need to write the formulas in php.

Comment: Think of lat/lon as X/Y. Then how is it different? (Remember you're working with a sphere here, so there's some 'wraparound' cases you might want to handle...). Also: you need to define 'opposing'; I'm pretty sure you don't want an **exact** (mathematical) 180 degree opposing but some 'margin'.

Comment: @RobIII well that could work, but I thought it would be a bit different considering the globe is a spheroid and I would have to take that into account(I think)

Comment: It depends on your requirements, but, yes, you *may* need to take that into account. You then need to add that to your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your Lattitude/Longitude to X/Y vector using @matri70boss link and then your 2 routes from A (xA, yA) to B (xB, yB) correspond each one to a vector v (xB-xA, yB-yA).

So you have 2 vectors v1 and v2 for your 2 routes. If you do the scalar product between them, the sign of the product will tell you if they point in the same direction (if positive : same direction, negative : opposite direction, =0 : perpendicular).

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79633/how-to-determine-vector-between-two-lat-lon-points to calculate it and then compare.